# VB.Net clear datagridview rows without the headers

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with columns added from the designer, the data for this grid will be selected from the database and will be directly bound to the grid. For this purpose I have DataPropertyName to the column names of the database table.

I am setting the datasource like this :

```
dgPayment.DataSource = myDatatable
```

Now I need to clear the rows of the datagridview without removing the headers of the datagridview. I tried using `dgPayment.Rows.Clear()`, but this prompted a error because the grid is bound & therefore the rows cannot be manually altered. I also tried setting the datasource to nothing like this :

`dgPayment.DataSource = Nothing`

But this removes the headers too, which doesn't need to happen because they are the column headers that I added using the designer. How can I clear only the data without clearing the headers.

Comment: try myDataTable.Rows.Clear()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
dataGridView1.DataSource.Rows.Clear()
```

Comment: @AseemGautam OP set is bound so i think datgridview have datasource. Its right?

Comment: This will not work if you use `Option Strict On` - which you should always use.

Answer (score 4):

If you create columns through designer, then in form `constructor` or in `Load` event handler put next line of code

```
dgPayment.AutoGenerateColumns = false
```

Then freely use `dgPayment.DataSource = Nothing` for removing all rows

Comment: Nice trick. I always use AutoGenerateColumns = false, but it never occured to me that placing it in Load event would prevent loosing columns. Now thre's no need for datatable workarounds...

Answer (score 2):

Remove only rows from the datatable.

`DataTable.Rows.Clear()`. This will keep the columns intact.

Then to refresh the data -

```
CurrencyManager cm = ((CurrencyManager)) dataGridView1.BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
cm.Refresh();
```

Comment: Clear datatable rows and not datagridview rows.

Comment: sry my mistake. I thought you mentioned datagridview.Rows.Clear()